# Beamer and bold math in cmbright

Tags: beamer, math-mode, fonts

I stumbled upon the following issue: the document

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{cmbright,amsmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
    \mathversion{bold} $a \cap b \cup c = \beta$ {\fontseries{sb}\slshape a,b,c}
\end{document}
```

compiles nicely to give [image]. However, if I change the document class to `beamer`, wrong font is selected for bold math letters (presumably `T1/cmbr/bx/n`?). The document:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{cmbright,amsmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \mathversion{bold} $a \cap b \cup c = \beta$ {\fontseries{sb}\slshape a,b,c}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

gives [image]. I tried to declare another math version:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{cmbright,amsmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\DeclareMathVersion{varbold}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}{varbold}{OML}{cmbrm}{b}{it}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \mathversion{varbold} $a \cap b \cap c = \beta$ {\fontseries{sb}\slshape a,b,c}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

or even using `\SetSymbolFont{letters}{varbold}{T1}{cmbr}{sb}{sl}` (which of course gives rubbish for everything except latin letters, but let that issue apart) does not give an improvement. What's happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `beamer` package redefines a number of fonts by default in order to get sans-serif math.  This clashes with `cmbright` (by redefining bold math to use `bx` rather than `sb`).

Since you already had the fonts set up the way you wanted them, suppress these redefinitions by adding the line

```
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
```

to your preamble.  You could also use the `professionalfonts` package option.

#### Edit

For once, it wasn’t me who submitted another answer about how, by the way, you could do this with `unicode-math` instead.

It’s a good answer!  With a few changes, it can even support the standard `\mathversion{bold}`, `\boldmath` and `\boldsymbol` commands.  I also set up `\sbseries` and `\textsb` commands analogous to `\bfseries` and `\textbf`.

```
\documentclass[professionalfonts]{beamer}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\defaultfontfeatures[FiraSans]{
  FontFace = {sb}{n}{FiraSans-Semibold.otf},
  FontFace = {sb}{sl}{FiraSans-SemiboldItalic.otf}
  FontFace = {sb}{it}{FiraSans-SemiboldItalic.otf}
}
\usepackage{FiraSans}
\usepackage{firamath-otf}

\DeclareRobustCommand\sbseries{\fontseries{sb}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textsc}{\sbseries}

\setmathfont[version=bold, FakeBold = 1.2]{Fira Math}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \mathversion{bold} $a \cap b \cup c = \beta$ {\sbseries\slshape a,b,c}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: Fira sample]

You can tweak the `FakeBold` value to make the font a bit darker if you want.

If you’re not planning to use both bold and semi-bold in the same document, which is usually not a good idea anyway, you could define the bold weight as semi-bold instead.

Answer (score 3):

Run with xelatex or lualatex:

```
\documentclass[professionalfonts]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{FiraSans}
\usepackage[fakebold]{firamath-otf}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

$a \cap b \cap c = \beta$ 

$\setBold a \cap b \cap c = \beta\unsetBold$

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice answer! I edited my own to talk about it a bit.